# PHP code to get particular portion from an array

Tags: php

I have a version variable like

```
$version = "3.4.5";
```

And a verison  array like

```
$verison= ["3.7.8", "3.5.2", "3.4.6", "3.3.2", "3.3.1", "3.2.1"];
```

I have to return an array from the `$verison` array which is greater than the verison string  `"3.4.5";`
The resultant array will be

```
$final=["3.7.8", "3.5.2", "3.4.6"]
```

How it can be perform with PHP code

Comment: You can't compare numer as strings. I think that you should iterate your list, convert the string elemnt into a number removing the points and then, compare with the version. if greatter, add it into a new list.

Comment: Did the version array sorted from high to low?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `array_filter` and `version_compare` :

```
$versions= ["3.7.8", "3.5.2", "3.4.6", "3.3.2", "3.3.1", "3.2.1"];
$version = "3.4.5";

$result = array_filter($versions, function($v) use ($version){return version_compare($v, $version, '>=');});

print_r($result);
```

outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3.7.8
    [1] => 3.5.2
    [2] => 3.4.6
)
```

Ref :
http://php.net/array_filter
http://php.net/version_compare

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_filter()` and you can compare the version string directly.

**Note:this may be only work for each subversion number just one char. If big than 9, you can split the version with `.`, can compare each subversion number seperately.**

[Demo](https://eval.in/899571).

```
array_filter($array, function($v) use ($version){return $v > $version;});
```

Comment: @Psl  you can `explode('.', $version)` to an array, then compare each element seperately. But I recomend Calimero's `version_compare` function and his answer.